# compute the inverse of linear equation to get the coefficients of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure if this is a silly question or not, but just bear with me. Giving the following linear equations 
$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{A}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\textbf{x}}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}  \\
b_{21}  \\
b_{31}  \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\textbf{b}}
$$

If $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{b}$ are given (i.e. they are non-zero), is it possible to compute $A$?

Comment: Well, if you are given just one pair, there may be many matrices that satisfy the equation (or none, if $x = 0$ and $b \neq 0$). If you are given many pairs ($x_k,b_k$) (and some conditions) then $A$ may be specified uniquely.

Comment: @copper.hat, $x \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By dividing across we may assume that $\|x\| = 1$.

Let $y_1,y_2\neq 0$ be unit vectors such that $y_k^T x = 0$ and $y_1^T y_2 = 0$. (This means that $x,y_1,y_2$ form an orthornormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.)

Then **all** solutions are given by $A=c_1 y_1^T + c_2 y_2^T +b x^T$, where $c_1, c_2$ are arbitrary. It is straightforward to confirm that $Ax = b$.

Comment: If you fix $c_1,c_2$ so that $c_1,c_2,b$ are orthogonal and add coefficients, you have a singular value decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

- If $b$ and $x$ are zero, then every $A$ is a solution.
- If $x$ is zero and $b$ is not, then there are no solutions
- If $x$ is non-zero, then there are infinitely many solutions

One solution can be given as follows: if $x_1$ is non-zero,
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
b_1/x_1&0&0\\
b_2/x_1&0&0\\
b_3/x_1&0&0
}
$$
Something similar can be done if any $x_i$ is non-zero.

Every solution to this equation can be written in the form $A + BC$, where $C$ is a matrix such that $Cx = 0$ and $B$ is any matrix at all.

Comment: both are non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not possible to compute uniquely the matrix $A$. Infact, suppose $B$ is another matrix such that $B \textbf{x} = 0$. Then $(A+B)\textbf{x} = \textbf{b}$.

An example of matrice $B$ such that $B \textbf{x} = 0$ is:
$$

\left[
\begin{matrix}
y & -x & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]

$$